# How to read each line of integers separately

Tags: java, arrays

I want to read a `m*n` matrix for example:

```
2 1 5;
3 1 3 1;
1 2;
```

I want to mark all the number down, for example, now the numbers being marked are 1, 2, 3, 5

Since I need to make sure the input of row = m, I want to read each line separately.

Here is my code, but it reads all the number into the same list, so I cannot make sure that there are only m row:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();                    
while (sc.hasNextInt())
    list.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Comment: You can split your list into n rows of m elements each after you finish reading the input. Otherwise, you should change your data structure from List<Integer> to something different.

Answer (score 0):

Before parsing the numbers, you could first extract each line based on the separator:

```
Scanner lineScanner = 
            new Scanner(System.in)
            .useDelimiter(";");
```

Then, read each line into its own array:

```
List<List<Integer>> lines = new ArrayList<>();

while(lineScanner.hasNext()) {
    List<Integer> newLine = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner rawLine = new Scanner(lineScanner.next());
    while(rawLine.hasNextInt()) {
        newLine.add(rawLine.nextInt());
    }
    lines.add(newLine);
}
```

With your input, `System.out.println(lines)` yields:

```
[[2, 1, 5], [3, 1, 3, 1], [1, 2]]
```

From there you can then easily check whatever you want on a per-line basis.

Comment: Hi @Shastick do you know how to stop the scanner of reading the input and print the output?

Comment: `Ctrl-D` works for me. Alternatively, you could first do something like `String input = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().`, and use `input` instead of System.in above. That will get things to work as soon as you hit `enter` after writing the line.